# Intellectually simple man crosses space border that kills the rest of the crew

Tags: story-identification, novel

I do not know the title or author. The main character is an intellectually simple man who ends up alone on a ship because it passed over some border in space. The border kills criminals (or something like that) and kills the rest of the crew. That’s near the beginning. I think he is stung or poisoned on the ship, but survives. I also remember a brilliant but cold woman in a wheelchair who is allowing some red mold to take her body. And I’m pretty sure the main character's sister features prominently.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please visit https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question and edit in any additional details you remember in answering those questions. Also, once someone posts the correct answer, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  When did you read this?  Do you remember what the cover looked like?

Comment: Not exactly the same, but "The Stars My Destination" does involve a single crewman escaping a dead ship in 'empty' space.

Comment: Also similar: some Steven King story where only the sleeping passengers remain on an airplane as it crosses a mystical border.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft "The Langoliers".

Answer (score 32):

[Hunted by James Alan Gardner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hunted_(Gardner_novel)).

> When new Explorer Corps recruit Edward York arrives on board the starship Willow, he abruptly becomes its sole survivor: everyone else simultaneously drops dead, executed by the near-omnipotent League of Peoples for violating its rule that anyone without sufficient respect for life is not allowed to travel between solar systems.
>
> Alone on a ship full of corpses, Edward discovers a complex plot involving the alien Mandasars, in whose decades-long civil war he had a cryptic role.

In chapter 3 (of 48) Edward is poisoned by the venom from a dead Mandasar hive queen when he interrupts nano-bots that are extracting the venom from the corpse.

The woman in the wheelchair with the red mold is described as follows:

> Just as I was finishing my story, I heard a whoosh coming up behind me. I spun around fast, thinking it might be the Larry back for another run… and Festina spun tight in unison with me, her fists up in guard position. Even Zeeleepull clicked his pincers to the ready, all three of us jumping like we’d heard a ghost. Which made it embarrassing when the noise turned out to be a lady in a wheelchair.
>
> Of course, regular wheelchairs don’t go whoosh; but this one had a tiny skimmer engine under the seat, strong enough to lift it to knee height off the ground so it could fly over sticks and tangles. The chair traveled slowly, half as fast as a baby’s crawl, keeping straight and upright so the passenger wouldn’t get jostled… but as stately as a bride inching down the aisle, the wheelchair-woman drifted up the hillside toward us.
>
> Because of the shadows under the trees, I couldn’t see the woman clearly… except for her legs. They glowed dim red, like embers in a campfire: one leg shone all the way to the hip, the other from her toes to the knee. The glow had a fuzzy look to it; as she got closer I realized she had luminescent moss slathered thick as carpet on her skin.
> Was that the fashion now, wearing patches of scarlet mold from ankle to thigh? Or could it be some medical treatment? The woman was in a wheelchair; maybe the moss was a sort of medicine, a nanotech foam working to repair whatever damage kept her from walking.

Edward's sister is Samantha. Both Edward and Samantha are near clones of their father:

> Of course, I wasn’t him exactly — the doctor who designed me started with Dad’s DNA, then fiddled with it to make me better. Samantha was exactly the same as me: the same person exactly, our dad’s clone, except she got an X chromosome where I got a Y.

Comment: Nothing says "sufficient respect for life" like summary executions. :)

Comment: @chepner according to the description, that “League of Peoples” doesn’t require showing “sufficient respect for life”, they only disallow “to travel between solar systems” for those who don’t. So if they do not travel themselves but are using other methods when doing remote mass killings, they do not violate their own rule.

Comment: @Holger They might only violate the spirit of their own rule, not the letter

Comment: What was the red mold about? I'm curious XD

Comment: @chepner, if the League has already applied due process to convict humans of "insufficient respect for life," and if their laws prescribe death for a convict who attempts to leave his/her system, …

Comment: @WGroleau Due process that didn't, apparently, involve notifying the defendants ;) (I'm being facetious, of course.)